# My chain skips on the front chain rings. What do I do?

Tags: mountain-bike, chainring

I currently ride a Cannondale Catalyst 3 and I've noticed my chain doesn't like to catch on my front chainrings. I'm very new to mountain biking and I am on a very low budget, so is there any way to fix this problem without spending $100? Do I have to get new chain rings, a new crankset, or something else? I'm a student and I don't have all those fancy tools that are specially designed for bike work. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: At the very least you need to replace the chain.

Answer (score 4):

Chains stretch over time and, as they do that, they wear the chain rings and cogs to match their new size.  By the time the chain starts skipping on the chain rings, the teeth have become so badly worn that there's no alternative to replacing the chain rings, chain and rear cogs.  Unfortunately, that probably will cost $75+ in parts.

The way to avoid this in future is to replace your chain before it's stretched so much that it destroys the rest of your drivetrain.  Chains themselves aren't very expensive and replacing them is one of the running costs of a bike. You can check how worn your chain is by using a [chain checker](https://www.parktool.com/product/chain-wear-indicator-cc-3-2) – you can get them more cheaply than the one I've linked to.

Comment: the thing is I just replaced the chain and cassette about 3 weeks ago but now its only slipping in the front and just does not want to switch gears like if I'm in 1rst and I switch to 2nd it takes like a couple seconds before it switches

Comment: Then it definitely sounds like you need new chain rings. Have a look at the teeth -- do they look like sharks' fins? ("Good" news -- you've already replaced two out of the three components I mentioned.)

Comment: some of them do look a little hooked mostly on the 2nd and 3rd rings

Comment: Sounds like that's the problem, then, especially if those are the ones you use most. You could add a picture to the question.

Comment: I currently cant add a picture but what would the cheapest price be for replacing my chainrings

Comment: I'm not sure. You'd have to check what you need and look for prices for that. A bike shop will be able to advise you, even if you do the work yourself.

Comment: @NathanPlumstead Identify your make/model of bicycle and post photos of your crankset and you'll likely get all kinds of responses identifying replacement chainrings.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The question says it's a Cannondale Catalyst 3.

Comment: the crank set is a prowheel 24/34/42 I think by shimano if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @NathanPlumstead "Prowheel" isn't a Shimano line that I recognize. But, anyway, you can look things up on the internet just as well as I can. In fact, you can do it better, because if I do it, I'm going to get British prices that aren't necessarily representative of what you'd have to pay.

Comment: ok thank  for the help

Comment: On the subject of affordable chain checkers, [twenty half-links in a new chain measure 10 inches (254 mm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain#Wear)

Answer (score 2):

Based on reading your question and the comments, I feel the combination of worn chainrings coupled with the new chain and cassette is causing your chain slip. 
The Cannondale Catalyst 3 sports a Prowheel triple crankset with 44/32/22 tooth rings. 
This is not Shimano brand but does share the same 104/64 mm BCD as Shimano rings of similar type.  Amazon lists a [Prowheel crankset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071Y3GZVY)
as you describe for around $68. Pretty reasonable as far as cranksets go, and I see some listings on a Google search for even less. It wouldn't be unreasonable to expect individual chainrings to run between $10-20, especially for the middle and  small ring.  A 5 or 6 mm hex wrench (aka: hex key) and standard screwdriver are tools needed for chainring replacement. If your system has an external bottom bracket, the cranks can be removed with a 5mm hex key at the pinch bolts of the left crank arm, and the preload bolt in the center can be engaged with a 10mm hex key or similarly large torx bit. This is NOT ideal as one is supposed to use a special tool that properly engages the splines of the bolt. This is also typically plastic and can be easily damaged.  However, there is not a great deal of torque required on this bolt so there's a bit of leeway there when one doesn't have specific "bike tools."

Comment: Torx isn't bike-specific _per se_ but I agree that it's somewhat specialist, which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Torx wrenches are readily available at hardware stores in the US.

Comment: My intention was to suggest tools that we're not bicycle-specific which is how I categorize a torx bit/wrench. Torx are readily available here...unless, of course, after combing through a jar full of Phillips-head screws, you finally come across the perfect one for your needs and the Phillips driver you wield, only to find the damned thing is Torx.